# Arrows in the center of swiper slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help me to write HTML and JS code for implementing arrows in the center of the slider like on the image below? I had a problem for some time doing this, so if anyone can come up with something, I would be very grateful. You can also visit https://xd.adobe.com/view/e9006d17-86b0-416d-b018-9c767c9cfc8f-bc53/ to see the arrows I'm talking about.

[swiper slider arrows in the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJasv.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The below code will help you in making the swiper arrows to the bottom center of the slider. You can adjust the `left` and `right` positions of the arrows by increasing or decreasing the `30px` provided according to your wish.

```
.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    bottom: 0;
    top: auto;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.swiper-button-prev {
    left: calc(50% - 30px);
}

.swiper-button-next {
    right: calc(50% - 30px);
}
```

Comment: Simple and clean, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        autoplay: 3500,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
            loop: true
    });
```

```css
.swiper_wrap{
  position:relative
}

.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev {
    bottom: -50px !important;
    top: unset !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}

.swiper-button-prev {
    left: -30px !important;
}

.swiper-button-next {
    left: 30px !important;
}

.swiper-slide img{
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <div class="container">

<div class="swiper_wrap">
<div class="slider-wrapper">
       <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/07/16/37/wood-591631_960_720.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/07/16/37/wood-591631_960_720.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/07/16/37/wood-591631_960_720.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/07/16/37/wood-591631_960_720.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div><div class="swiper-slide">
                    <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/07/16/37/wood-591631_960_720.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
       <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>   
</div>
</div>
<script src="http://www.jakse.si/test/jakse/taxi/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```